# Setting up E-mail server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mail-server

I am totally messed-up while installing mail server in Ubuntu system.

My purpose is:

1. To set up a local mail server which will fetch mails from an external server in deliver the same to the local clients like outlook
2. The mails sent through the outlook clients to other recipients would be forwarded to them, not directly, but through this local server.

For example, there are 5 users having account in **gmail.com**: **user1@gmail.com, 
user2@gmail.com, user3@gmail.com, user4@gmail.com, user5@gmail.com**. Now, my purpose is to fetch those mails into **my-local server** so that users get access to them. Also, their sent mails would be collected in this mail server, and forwarded to gmail for forwarding (The clients would be configured so).

Please help

Comment: Got server questions? Try: [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you on setting up ubuntu mail server http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/